# Searching all public variables of objects in List<T> for specific string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I'm trying to see if it is possible to search all public variables that have a .ToString() method of any given object with Linq.

Basically I want to supply two paramaters, a `List<T>` to search and a `string` and get returned a `List<T>` of objects that had one or more public variables that contained my string.

I can get all public properties of an object using

```
Type objectType = _data[0].GetType();
var properties = objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
var fields = objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

But I'm stuck on how I should use this to search the list of objects without looping over all objects and all their properties.

Comment: But you want/need to loop over all objects and properties, right?

Comment: "all public variables that have a .ToString() method". Every object in .Net has a `ToString();` method.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I'm guessing OP may mean "that _override_ .ToString()", or more precisely, that have a .ToString() implementation that is not inherited from Object.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Correct, if toString() returns something like System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleTest.DataObject], then that does not help me much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a complete example:

*(Note: I will edit this answer to take into account `ToString()` override)*

EDIT: Done

```
public class Program
{
    public class ToStringNotOverrided0 { }
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public string str;
    public ToStringNotOverrided0 toStringNotOverrided;

    public static IEnumerable<T> getMatches<T>(List<T> list, string search) {
        if (search == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("search");
        return list.Select(x => new
        {
            X = x,
            Props = x.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public),
            Fields = x.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public),
        })
        .Where(x => x.Props.Any(p =>
                            {
                                var val = p.GetValue(x.X, null);
                                return val != null
                                    && val.GetType().GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes).DeclaringType == val.GetType()
                                    && val.ToString().Contains(search);
                            })
                    || x.Fields.Any(p =>
                            {
                                var val = p.GetValue(x.X);
                                return val != null
                                    && val.GetType().GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes).DeclaringType == val.GetType()
                                    && val.ToString().Contains(search);
                            }))
        .Select(x => x.X);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Program> list = new List<Program>{
            new Program { Int = 0, str = "foo bar" , toStringNotOverrided = new ToStringNotOverrided0()},
            new Program { Int = 54, str = "foo 0 bar"  , toStringNotOverrided = new ToStringNotOverrided0()},
            new Program { Int = 12, str = "foo bar"  , toStringNotOverrided = new ToStringNotOverrided0()},
            new Program { Int = 720, str = "foo bar" , toStringNotOverrided = new ToStringNotOverrided0() }
        };
        foreach (var item in getMatches(list, "0"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Int = " + item.Int 
                + ", str = " + item.str
                + ", toStringNotOverrided = " + item.toStringNotOverrided);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
bool isMethodExist = type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
```

if you have `List<T>`

```
var type = _data.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
bool isMethodExist = type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
```